# Samba Shares from Windows only by IP

Tags: windows-7, samba, netbios

I have Ubuntu Server (10.10) running. There are two server components active: The fileserver is Samba and OpenSSH for remote access. It is a home network, (workgroup).

When I use OpenSSH from windows, the servername can be used instead of an Ip (servername.local)

When I ping servername.local from windows, the IP is resolved.

When I try to connect to a Samba share from Windows (win7) I need to supply the ip address. I can't use the computername. Is it possible to configure this in a way that I can use computername instead?

Thanks,
Sander

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like Windows 7 doesn't have a NetBIOS client running. Can you run nbstat?

To get this working in a small environment you can use the hosts file for simple name resolution.  This is probably the better option rather than trying to get NetBIOS running on Windows 7 (if it is indeed unsupported.)  DNS would also be over kill.

Also, please be aware that serverfault is intended for professional system administrators. ([serverfault.com/faq](https://serverfault.com/faq)) This sort of question relating to a home network is better suited to superuser.com. ([superuser.com/faq](https://superuser.com/faq))

Comment: Thanks. I will use supersuser next time. I can't find nbstat on my win7 at the moment. But adjusting the host file works for now.